# Can Microsoft Reporting Services be used to create single-page special forms?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and I'm looking for a good reporting tool. I like what I see with Reporting Services for most column based reports, but can it also be used to create special printed forms, such as a check or an employee W2 form?

These type of forms are not column based, so I'm thinking I'd have to use a single row and column and put all the fields within it. However, I don't see a way to align some text left and some right or to put fields in a fixed position. If I can't do that then it's not possible.

I'm doing ASP.NET web programming here, so I think the right answer is to use something else to generate a PDF instead for these special types of forms, but I want to make sure there isn't a way to use Reporting Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is most reports are table based with fixed rows and columns.  To get the appearance you want with say a W2 form is almost impossible.  It would have to done via a combination of objects within the report.  For instance here is a sample of a report I do for an expense report system:

[image]

I use a combination of tables, matrices, and lists just to make one report whose result looks like this:

[image]

Its very difficult to get it exactly the way you want, you have to play with reporting services to get it close to the way you want.  I will not knock reporting services, it is an AWESOME tool, I love using it and it is my preferred choice (over CR crystal reports or any other 3rd party solution).  But something as custom as a w2 you may have to generate on the fly and print to pdf.  Kind of like what turbo tax does.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

SSRS custom formatting for these types of forms is rudimentary and difficult at best. That is if you want more that a glorified spreadsheet look. the 'report wizard in Visual Studio will get you part way however most will have to be trial and error.

Cognos ReportNet is a far superior tool however you have to work with what you are given.